# Estimating the geometric shape of a point cloud without using the vertex information

Tags: probability, 3d, computational-geometry, geometry

Consider a point cloud format that describes 3D point clouds by vertices, triangle labels and normal vectors. If we miss the vertex information, is it possible to retrieve the lost data by triangle labels and normal vectors. Can we guess the geometric shape of the point cloud? Thank you for your insights.

Comment: Define "geometric shape". Have you looked at alpha shapes? I don't think clustering is what you are looking for. Why would you lose vertex information the first place?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse thanks for your comment. By geometric shape, I mean the definition presented at http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_shapes.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse yes, I looked at alpha shapes (bernardini & Bajaj, 1997). But my problem is different. I don't have the vertex information.